# DATABASE_URL is not set(CS50)

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I'm working on cs50 project1 (js & python), I download the project, 
and found this line in it:

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
```

the question is how to set up the DATABASE_URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this code after initialising your app:

`app.config['DATABASE_URL'] = "path_to_db"`

Or export it by running in your command line:

`export DATABASE_URL=""postgres://user:password@server_ip:5432/table_name""`

Answer (score 2):

If you use Linux you could set variable in environment via:

```
 $ export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://localhost/yourdatabase"
```